# Issue on Creating module?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I am trying to learn module programming for that i used a sample program in c as

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello man .\n");
return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Good bye see you soon\n");
}
```

for compiling this c code i wrote a make file as below

```
    obj-m + = Hello_module.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Then i am compiling this one using make command i get following errors

```
joe@joe-O-E-M:~/Module_pgm$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/build M=/home/joe/Module_pgmmodules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
./scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/joe/Module_pgmmodules/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/joe/Module_pgmmodules/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/joe/Module_pgmmodules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can i resolve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space between `$(PWD)` and `modules`. Try:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

The "No such file or directory" error message shows the path it's trying to find.

Comment: I made the change as per recommended above but currently there is no error while compiling but there is no object file is generated!!!!!

Comment: You must define your two function as module_init/module_exit functions. Add module_init(init_module); and module_exit(cleanup_module); at the end of your Hello_module.c file